# Multiple files not getting uploaded to the server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload

was trying to upload multiple files in the server using `multiparty`. On the server side getting  two files but while writing only single file is getting uploaded. When I debugged the  code I found that before file read happening control is heading back to the beginning of the for loop. As a result the most recent file in the object is only processed for upload. Why this is happening ? Below is the code for the same.

```
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){   
          var fileArry=files.uploadFiles;
                if(fileArry.length == 0){
                    console.log(" No file found to  upload !!!");
                    res.send('No files found to upload.');
                            return; 
                }
                for(var i=0; i<fileArry.length ; i++)
                {  
                    newPath='./uploads/';
                    singleFile=fileArry[i];

                    console.log("::::::::::::::::::::: This is the single file and it  path ::::::::::::::::::::::::");                         
                    console.log(singleFile);

                    newPath+=singleFile.originalFilename;

                    console.log("::::::::::::::::::::: New file path is :"+newPath)         
                    console.log("::::::::::::::::::::: Going inside file  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
                        
                    fs.readFile(singleFile.path, (err, data) => {
                       fs.writeFile(newPath, data, (err) => {                       
                         console.log("Files uploaded "+newPath);
                                    });
                                });                                 
                          }
                        res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
                });
```

The result after debugging is [image] -

How to overcome this and upload multiple files at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for several hours and doing a number of google searches came across a similar situation on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581117/reading-multiple-files-in-parallel-and-writing-the-data-in-new-files-accordingly) and yes it did solve my problem. As per the link, the changed code is as below and it is working for uploading multiple file.

```
app.post('/multiFileUpload', function(req, res) {

    var singleFile;     
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

   form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){    
      var fileArry=files.uploadFiles;                   
                if(fileArry.length == 0){
                    res.send('No files found to upload.');
                        return; 
                }

                    for(i=0; i<fileArry.length; i++)
                    {  
                        newPath='./uploads/';
                        singleFile=fileArry[i];
                        newPath+=singleFile.originalFilename;
                        readAndWriteFile(singleFile,newPath);                       
                    }
                    res.send("File uploaded to: " + newPath);
            });

});

 function readAndWriteFile(singleFile , newPath){

    fs.readFile(singleFile.path, (err, data)=>{
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, (err)=>{                                                                                                                
                console.log("File uploaded to  :"+newPath);
            });
    });
}
```